# ios - UI table view cell problem

Tags: ios, accessoryview

This is the first time i am using the accessory view in my app. So i have some problem in that, please help me friends

in my app i have placed an accessory view inside an UI Table View Cell. When i swipe over the UI table view cell to delete that row the accessory view completely gets hidden(it shows the delete button in red color and rest of the part appears to be a blank white space). But when i swipe it i want the accessory view to be visible along with the button. I want the text to be in a highlighted manner, how to get those accessory view without making them hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siva K

Your tableViewCell has *editingAccessoryView* and *editingAccessoryType* properties. If you use custom accessory view you should set the former of them to your accessory view, if you use system one set according value to the last.